# Revealing module pattern and chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

This is the code that i found here: [link](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript)

```
var myRevealingModule = (function () {

    var privateCounter = 0;

    function privateFunction() {
      privateCounter++;
    }

    function publicFunction() {
        publicIncrement();
    }

    function publicIncrement() {
        privateFunction();
    }

    function publicGetCount(){
      return privateCounter;
    }

    // Reveal public pointers to
    // private functions and properties

   return {
        start: publicFunction,
        increment: publicIncrement,
        count: publicGetCount
    };

})();

myRevealingModule.start();
```

the code  works as   exptected, but why if I paste the code on chrome console i get undefined?

Thanks

Comment: myRevealingModule.count() does return 1.there is nothing wrong in the code

Comment: Works fine for me: http://codepen.io/BrianGenisio/pen/LaeyB

Comment: Are you expecting `start()` to return `1`?  Because it doesn't return anything.  You need to call `count()`

Comment: You are right guys i've corrected the question . Anyway why if I paste the code on chrome console i get undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing `undefined` displayed by the console because it is displaying the return value of the `start` function. In your code, that is calling `publicFunction` which will return undefined.  If you specifically return something from that function, you will see that value displayed in the Chrome console instead.